# How to create small SPACES in HTML?

Tags: html, layout, typography

There is em dash and en dash. Is there an "en" equivalent to *&nbsp;* ? Is there an *en* equivalent to pure *Ascii 32*?

I want a better way to write this:

```
123<span class="spanen">&nbsp;</span>456<span class="spanen">&nbsp;</span>789
```

or this:

```
123<span class="spanen"> </span>456<span class="spanen"> </span>789
```

Comment: `&ensp;` for en-space, `&emsp;` for em-space, and `&puncsp;` for punctuation-space. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8515365/632951 for more info. Btw, what do you mean by *"en equivalent to pure Ascii 32"*?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't use hacks that make no sense. If you wish to separate some words, I suggest you use the CSS property [word-spacing](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/word-spacing/):

```css
.strangeNumbers {
  word-spacing: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<span class="strangeNumbers">123 456</span>
```

Comment: do you know if all modern browsers do this?

Comment: Of course you have to use `white-space: nowrap;` to make sure this number will not split into two lines.

Comment: Nice, but better to use `&nbsp;` instead of space.

Comment: @elmigranto why? I now think there must be a Unicode non-breaking-space character to separate numbers, like OP wanted, and that it would be the best pick. But if not using that exact character then I would prefer to use css's `word-spacing` and `white-space:nowrap;`, instead of a wrong character.

Comment: @ANeves, I just wanted to point out that breaking a line in the middle of some cash amount (for example) would look ugly. Never heard about Unicode nbsp, not so advanced in css either. My bad :)

Comment: (@elmigranto Ah, you're right that it is better to use html entities to represent the characters, rather than writing the character. [Either in Unicode or another character encoding.])

Comment: .. and use negative word-spacing for a smaller-than-normal space

Comment: Spacing features are built into (good) modern fonts, and aren't "hacks". See a much better answer with examples of many different kinds of spaces here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8515417/1327983

Answer (score 61):

`&thinsp;` (thin space) should do

Note that `&nbsp;` does not have the same width as an `&mdash;` (—); to separate numbers you should use a narrow no-break space (U+202F).

As others have mentioned, you are better off using the CSS property `word-spacing` to define the width of your spaces. It is probably a good idea to combine it with `white-space:nowrap;` to avoid breaking lines between groups of numbers and keep the full number on a single line.

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for in the first place. but i accepted the css answer, because it is even better and is also answering the question how i wrote it.

Comment: as i said in my answer: go with word-spacing and white-space properties

Comment: If you use _white-space_ property, remember the value is "_nowrap_" instead of the suggested "_no-break_"

Comment: You also have even narrower `&hairsp;` and many other choices: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8515417/1327983

Answer (score 14):

The Unicode character U+2002 *EN SPACE* (`&#x2002;`, `&#8194;` or as entity reference `&ensp;`) is a space with en width.

Comment: same here: this is exactly what i was looking for in the first place. but i accepted the css answer, because it is even better and is also answering the question how i wrote it.

Comment: This is, however, not exactly a small space after all.

Answer (score 7):

```
&thinsp;
```

... and various other non-standard space characters are not properly implemented in some fixed fonts.

This will will foul up your rendering on the web browser end in an uncontrollable manner, and you can't fix it by being specific about the font, because you can't control what actual font is being used by the web browser — even if you specify the font-name or font-family, that doesn't mean the font they have is the same as the font *you* have.

But you can build a 100%-compatible space of any size you want, though, and it's very easy. The *em* value is the *current* `font-size`. It's the height, but whatever the width of the font is, it's always a constant relative to the height in a fixed-width font. So you can take advantage of that.

Here's how to make a **1/2 width, non-breaking space** within the context of a fixed-width font that works with *everything*. I show it implemented in a span's `style=""` option, but of course you can make a CSS class instead to make its use less clumsy:

```
<span style="font-size: .5em;">&nbsp;</span>
```

Here's how to make a **1/4 width, non-breaking** space:

```
<span style="font-size: .25em;">&nbsp;</span>
```

...and so on.

This always works with space sizes smaller than the current full-width space because the character is shorter than the other characters on the line, so they control the line spacing, not the shorter character.

If you want a space that is *wider* than one space, use a combination of full spaces and shorter spaces. While you *will* get a wider space if you use something like `1.5em`, you will also get a taller space, and so that will affect the line spacing.

While this solution is annoyingly cumbersome, it has the desirable attribute of *always* working — which none of the others do.

Answer (score 2):

You could alter your CSS in such:

```
.spanen{word-spacing:.6em;}
```

Comment: austin, thank you. this is quite the same as the accepted answer. the other was earlier, so what can i do

Comment: +1: pardon, but mine wasn't earlier. When I posted my answer I saw austin's, and the only reason I didn't delete mine was that I felt mine was a bit more complete.