# Are there other whitespace codes like &nbsp for half-spaces, em-spaces, en-spaces etc useful in HTML?

Tags: html

Wondering if there are other codes available to use in an HTML newsletter.

I would use cell padding or margins but I'm new to this HTML/CSS thing and I can't find a change that does effect both the Main Title line and the sub-head under it. Being an email I'm hesitant to go mucking around with the CSS to get it just so — since I don't know what email clients don't like in the way of CSS as opposed to inline markup.

For context the template I'm using is Mute theme from Mailchimp snip:

```
    <!-- language: lang-html -->
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="626">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="middle" bgcolor="#546781" height="97" background="images/header-bg.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="555" height="97">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="middle" width="160" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align: left;">
                                <img width="70" height="70" src="http://dl.dropbox.com/…….png" style="margin:0; margin-top: 4px; display: block;" alt="" />
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;">
                                <h1 class="title" style="margin:0; padding:0; font-size:30px; font-weight: normal; color: #192c45 !important;">
                                    <singleline label="Title"><span>Title of Report</span></singleline>
                                </h1>
                                <h1 class="title" style="margin:0; padding:0; font-size:15px; font-weight: normal; color: #192c45 !important;">
                                    <singleline label="Title"><span>Small Subhead</span></singleline>
                                </h1>
                            </td>
                            <td width="55" valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align: center;">
                                <h2 class="date" style="margin:0; padding:0; font-size:13px; font-weight: normal; color: #192c45 !important; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; line-height:1;">
                                    <currentmonthname />December
                                </h2>
                                <h2 class="date" style="margin:0; padding:0; font-size:23px; font-weight: normal; color: #192c45 !important; font-weight: bold;">
                                     <currentyear />2011
                                </h2>
                            </td>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 571, accepted):

Yes, [many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_character#Spaces_in_Unicode).

Including, but not limited to:

- [ ] hair space : `&#8202;` or `&hairsp;`
- [ ] 6-per-em space : `&#8198;` <sub><sup>(no character reference available)</sup></sub>
- [ ] narrow no-break space : `&#8239;` <sub><sup>(no character reference available)</sup></sub>
- [ ] thin space : `&#8201;` or `&thinsp;`
- [ ] 4-per-em space : `&#8197;` or `&emsp14;`
- [ ] non breaking space : `&#160;` or `&nbsp;`
- [ ] punctuation space : `&#8200;` or `&puncsp;`
- [ ] 3-per-em space : `&#8196;` or `&emsp13;`
- [ ] en space : `&#8194;` or `&ensp;`
- [ ] figure space : `&#8199;` or `&numsp;`
- [ ] em space : `&#8195;` or `&emsp;`

```css
span{background-color: red;}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>non breaking space:</td><td> <span>&#160;</span> or <span>&nbsp;</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>narrow no-break space:</td><td> <span>&#8239;</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>en space:</td><td> <span>&#8194;</span> or <span>&ensp;</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>em space:</td><td> <span>&#8195;</span> or <span>&emsp;</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>3-per-em space:</td><td> <span>&#8196;</span> or <span>&emsp13;</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>4-per-em space:</td><td> <span>&#8197;</span> or <span>&emsp14;</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>6-per-em space:</td><td> <span>&#8198;</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>figure space:</td><td> <span>&#8199;</span> or <span>&numsp;</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>punctuation space:</td><td> <span>&#8200;</span> or <span>&puncsp;</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>thin space:</td><td> <span>&#8201;</span> or <span>&thinsp;</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>hair space:</td><td> <span>&#8202;</span> or <span>&hairsp;</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Firefox renders all of the above spaces as the same width, wider than one space in the font, except for nbsp, where it renders as one space and imposes the non-breaking character. A real shame. There are cases where only a character will do, for instance when padding is being controled or passed to something else with constructs like `before:`

Comment: @fyngyrz At least in Firefox 54 on Linux, this is not true (anymore). It may also depend on the font though; I've tested this on Stack Overflow, where the Arial font family is used.

Comment: For anybody who just wants to see how this whitespace types look like https://jsfiddle.net/LcLg5u25/

Comment: figure space `$numsp;` is very useful for aligning numbers, because the space is defined to be exactly as wide as a number in the same font.

Comment: ^ assuming mono-spaced numbers presumably. sometimes monospaced numeral glyphs are not the default number glyphs in a font face, but provided as additional glyphs.

Comment: Cool code snippet BTW, that's new since I posed this question a long time ago. Thx @Christoph !!

Comment: Firefox on Windows is fine now (v.61) BTW.

Comment: @bookcasey This is an incredible answer and I will be using it for years and years.

Comment: Down marked for using decimal entities (e.g. `&#8239;`).  Unicode values are *invariably* written using hexadecimal values.  If you write `&#x202F;` there's a chance it may be recognised, and even if the precise character is not recognised, someone reading the source may well recognise it as part of the general punctuation block.  There's absolutely no good reason to use decimal values.

Answer (score 14):

There are codes for other space characters, and the codes as such work well, but the characters themselves are legacy character. They have been included into character sets only due to their presence in existing character data, rather than for use in new documents. For some combinations of font and browser version, they may cause a generic glyph of unrepresentable character to be shown. For details, check my [page about Unicode spaces](https://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html).

So using CSS is safer and lets you specify any desired amount of spacing, not just the specific widths of fixed-width spaces. If you just want to have added spacing around your h2 elements, as it seems to me, then setting padding on those elements (changing the value of the padding: 0 settings that you already have) should work fine.

Comment: Thanks I ended up using the inline attribute 
<h1 class="title" style="margin:0; margin-left: 2px; padding:0; font-size:15px; font-weight: normal; color: #192c45 !important;">

I guess that's safest even though the font family is Helvetica Neue etc

Comment: But if they're legacy and 'included into character sets only due to their presence in existing character data' that means they're not going away anytime soon. I don't really see you argument. I assume anyone 'advanced' enough to be looking for 'half spaces' has probably already decided that margin or padding aren't appropriate.  I settled on `(&thinsp;4 PACK&thinsp;)` for my requirements - using margin or padding would be a terrible idea for this

Comment: @Simon_Weaver, as I describe, fixed-width space characters do not work reliably. They are also a blunt tool: a fixed set of widths, though the actual widths are font-dependent, as opposite to font-independent settings like `<span style="padding: 0 0.1em">4 PACK</span>`, with freedom in setting and tuning the values.

Comment: Although it's quite old, Peter K Sheerin's "The Trouble With EM ’n EN (and Other Shady Characters)" (http://alistapart.com/article/emen) is still useful reading on this topic. In particular—although this may have improved over the last 14 years—the fact that not all f̶o̶n̶t̶s̶ typefaces render the various spaces correctly.

Comment: There are also `ZERO WIDTH JOINER` https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm and `ZERO WIDTH NON JOINER` that I tend to use more often than the zero-width spaces.

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if this is what you're referring to, but this is the list of HTML entities you can use:

[List of XML and HTML character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Using the content within the 'Name' column you can just wrap these in an `&` and `;`

E.g.
`&nbsp;`, `&emsp;`, etc.

Comment: So in context of marked up text (say inside '<p>' and '</p>' the '&' denotes a unicode glyph name, right? What is the ';' for that a space char doesn't signal when it's parsed by the browser?

Comment: The closing semi colon is optional in a sense as the HTML parser will still see whitespace as the end of the reference. However the specification states that you "must" end with a semicolon (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references)

Comment: PS - I would still appreciate it if you mark this as the answer - if you do feel this has answered your question :)

Answer (score 5):

What about normal encoded white-space character?

```
&#32;
```

Answer (score 4):

I used this Unicode Decimal Code `&#8204;` and worked. [more details](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/8204)

Comment: The zero width non-joiner (which you linked) isn't a space character. It doesn't take up any space, and isn't treated as a word separator. The only purpose it has is preventing adjacent characters from being joined into a ligature, which is sometimes useful in non-Latin scripts.

Comment: This character is great. That's just what I needed for forcing the browser not to ignore newlines at the end of a paragraph.