# Smaller space than &nbsp;

Tags: html, unicode

Are there characters that are "smaller" (e.g. half the size) than `&nbsp;`?

I am laying out my contact details on my website like so:

I'm trying to align my phone number with the email address above it:

```
Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;email address here
Tel&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; telephone number here
```

If I was to add yet another non-breaking space the number would move too far right.

Comment: A code example would be useful (even though I think I would not want to see it) - http://i.imgur.com/D9dQr.jpg

Comment: Could you post the entirety of your code please?

Comment: Don't abuse whitespace characters for alignment

Comment: Please add relevant code

Comment: There is no need to be rude Scorpion and Jon -- I am a designer by trade and I am learning to ropes of HTML and CSS. Comments like yours don't inspire me to ask questions on forums like this.

Comment: @Roopendra Okay, here's the code. Also the Email info should be linked to open up an email addressed to me in the visitor's email client. The Twitter info should link to Twit page. HTML here:
<div id="rightbaremail">
<a href="mailto:****.co.uk"><font color="#333333">Email:&nbsp; &nbsp; ****.co.uk</a></p>
</div>

<div id="rightbartel"> Tel:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&thinsp;123456789<br />
</div>


<div id="rightbartwitter">
<a href="https://twitter.com/Liza_****"><font color="#333333">Twitter:&nbsp; @Liza_****</a></p>
</div>

Comment: @user3069987: Thanks for posting codes. As you have accepted one answer so it seems your problem has been already resolved. If you still facing the issue then please let me know. We will add your relevant code in your question.

Comment: @user3069987, You can use `&#8239;` (the narrow nbsp). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8515365/632951 for more options.

Comment: It's hardly abuse. It's just.. use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree with the other answerers, you are definitely using the wrong tool. If you are a beginner and CSS is over your head, use a table, it's really simple:

```
<table>
  <tr> <td>Email</td> <td>whatever</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>Tel.</td>  <td>012345</td> </tr>
</table>
```

However for anybody who is really in need of unusual spaces, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) has an overwhelming selection. Notably there is thin space (`&thinsp;`, breaking) and Narrow No-Break Space (`#x202F;`, non-breaking).

Comment: However, I'd like to link the email info to open up a fresh email to me in the visitor's email client once clicked. How would you suggest I do this? This is why I was treating each piece of info differently.

Comment: Like this: <a href="mailto:adress@example.com">Click here to mail me!</a>

Answer (score 6):

You're barking up the wrong tree. Markup your data properly and align it using CSS, not using spaces or tabs. That's fundamentally a futile approach. E.g.:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Telephone</dt>
    <dd>012 3456 6789</dd>

    <dt>Email</dt>
    <dd>foo@example.com</dd>
</dl>

dl {
    overflow: hidden;
}

dt {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 150px;
}

dd {
    margin-left: 170px;
}
```

Comment: Imho the best approach, since the html reflects the semantics of the content.

Answer (score 2):

The method you have chosen to align email and telephone is frankly straight out of the dark ages. There are modern ways to do this that will do the job in a much saner and more maintainable manner, i.e. using appropriate HTML and CSS:

```
<label>Email:</label> email address here
<label>Tel:</label> telephone here
```

Apply a uniform `width` to the labels with CSS and you are good to go:

```
label { width: 5em; display: inline-block }
```

Even something as basic as the above gives you bonuses like the ability to modify the width of all labels at once and choose left or right justification "for free" on top of justifying the content.

**[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/TEjdW/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use css attribute 'margin-left' by creating span tags for email and phone no.
In css you can able to assign margin in pixel

Answer (score 0):

Space was looking too big so I added padding instead. Margin can also be used as it makes no difference here.

`-xLTx-` means to put the less than `<` character in there.

You can use:
`-xLTx-h1>Save/Retreive-xGTx-span style="padding-left:5px;">Data-LTx-/span>-xLTx-/h1>`

You could also use:
`-xLTx-h1>Save/Retreive-xLTx-span style="margin-left:5px;">Data-xLTx-/span>-xLTx-/h1>`

Adjust the padding or margin to your liking.