# Tell Webassets not to minify some code

Tags: python, flask, webassets, flask-assets

I am using Flask Assets which uses Webassets. It does a great job of stripping my HTML.

However it strips whitespace in one area where I do not want whitespace to be stripped. Is there a way to tell webassets not to strip the whitespace from one area of code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to prevent webassets to strip spaces only from a part of a file that you are minifying. You can either implement [your own filter](https://webassets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/custom_filters.html#the-easy-way) (or inherit the one you use now) and mark the area with some custom tags and leave that out for stripping OR you could use the non-breaking space code (`&nbsp;`) instead of spaces (`" "`) in that part of the HTML (though it has a slightly [different behavior](http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/www_faq/nbsp.html), check if that complies your use-case) instead of spaces. In that case they wont be stripped. Check the other codes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515365/are-there-other-whitespace-codes-like-nbsp-for-half-spaces-em-spaces-en-space).