# How prevent whitespace in input field with plain javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an username input field and trying to prevent user fill them with white spaces.

```
<input type="text" name="username" />
```

i do this and whitespace isn't blocked

```
var
  field = document.querySelector('[name="username"]');

field.addEventListener('keypress', function ( event ) {  
   var 
     key = event.keyCode;

   return (key !== 32);
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent its default behavior.

```js
var field = document.querySelector('[name="username"]');

field.addEventListener('keypress', function ( event ) {  
   var key = event.keyCode;
    if (key === 32) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="username" />
```

If you want to use the `return false;`, then you should use the `onkeypress` of the input instead, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgrpxj9p/)

```
field.onkeypress = function(e) {
   var  key = e.keyCode;
   return (key !== 32);
};
```

Comment: That is not enough when content come from a copy-paste, or when the textbox is auto-filled by the browser.

Comment: This doesn't prevent whitespace at all. It prevents the space key only. There are like 45 other ways the input can get whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

Modify the input like:

```
<input type="text" name="username" onkeypress="CheckSpace(event)"/>
```

Then the javascript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function CheckSpace(event)
{
   if(event.which ==32)
   {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try checking for all the different kinds of whitespaces listed here [Are there other whitespace codes like &nbsp for half-spaces, em-spaces, en-spaces etc useful in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515365/are-there-other-whitespace-codes-like-nbsp-for-half-spaces-em-spaces-en-space)

So you code would be:

```
var field = document.querySelector('[name="username"]');

field.addEventListener('keypress', function ( event ) {  
   var 
   key = event.keyCode;

   return (key !== 32 && key !== 160 && key != 5760 && key != 8192 && key != 8192 && key != 8194 && key != 8195 && key != 8196 && key != 8197 && key != 8198 && key != 8199 && key != 8200 && key != 8201 && key != 8202 && key != 8232 && key != 8233 && key != 8239 && key != 8287 && key != 12288);
});
```

Here is the complete list of all the different kinds of whitespaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Spaces_in_Unicode

Comment: Just saw the answer by @fuyushimoya, it would probably be good anyways to check for the different kinds of whitespaces

Comment: so it doesn't work in android mobile. When someone using an android mobile to register then he can put space in the user name. So how to stop that ? I think instead of key value we should do something new like replacing spaces. also copy past with space can escape this system

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone needs this to be done which will replace all whitespace automatically and will not allow user to put space and will force them to put username without space even then copy paste . Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var field = document.querySelector('[name="username"]');

field.addEventListener('keyup', function ( event ) {  
   var userName = field.value;
  userName = userName.replace(/\s/g, '');
  field.value = userName;
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML only solution using the `pattern` attribute and regex.

```html
<form>
 <input type="text" name="username" pattern="[^\s]+">
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        const key = e.keyCode
        const keyCodes = [
          32, 160, 5760, 8192, 8192, 8194, 8195, 8196, 8197, 8198, 8199,
          8200, 8201, 8202, 8232, 8233, 8239, 8287, 12288,
        ]
        if (keyCodes.some((val) => val === key)) {
          e.preventDefault()
        }
```

here is a simple solution !

Answer (score 0):

Hey i have simple solution regarding your question try one

If you want to submit only text and whitespace than use this one

```
<input type="text" name="Name" required pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" >
```

If you want to submit number and whitespace than use this one

```
<input type="text" name="Name" required pattern="[0-9 ]+" >
```

If you want to insert text not whitespace than use this one

```
<input type="text" name="Name" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" >
```

Use any line according to your requirements no extra line of code or condition simple and secure