# What is normal HTML line break behavior?

Tags: html, whitespace, line-breaks, definition, soft-hyphen

I am looking for a list of caracters and elements that may break HTML lines such as whitespaces but I can't find any page on the Internet with a definition of what is the normal HTML line break behavior.
I have found those :

- divisable space,
- tab,
- new line
- Zero-width space (asian)
- less "-"
- Soft-hyphen

I am not expecting it to break in the "pre" tag, of course!

Comment: in HTML si br tag  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Comment: You mean if a div is too short for the text, what would make the text go to the next line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515365/are-there-other-whitespace-codes-like-nbsp-for-half-spaces-em-spaces-en-space

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you want to know what characters create a [soft wrap opportunity](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#soft-wrap-opportunity), that is, they allow a line break in order to fit the content within the measure.

The answer is that it's not fully defined, and depends on the language:

> In most writing systems, in the absence of hyphenation a [soft wrap
>   opportunity](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#soft-wrap-opportunity) occurs only at word boundaries. Many such systems use
>   spaces or punctuation to explicitly separate words, and [soft wrap
>   opportunities](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#soft-wrap-opportunity) can be identified by these characters. Scripts such as
>   Thai, Lao, and Khmer, however, do not use spaces or punctuation to
>   separate words. Although the zero width space (U+200B) can be used as
>   an explicit word delimiter in these scripts, this practice is not
>   common.
>
> [...] CSS does not fully define where soft wrap opportunities occur, however
>   some controls are provided to distinguish common variations.

You can partially control this behavior using some CSS properties like

- [`line-break`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#line-break-property), to specify how wrapping interacts with punctuation and symbols
- [`word-break`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#word-break-property), which may allow soft wrap opportunities between letters
- [`hyphens`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#hyphens-property), to control whether hyphenation is allowed to create more soft wrap opportunities
- [`overflow-wrap`/`word-wrap`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#overflow-wrap-property), which may allow arbitrary breaks within a word to prevent overflow

If you want the full list of characters that create a soft wrap opportunity, you can use JS:

```js
var log = console.log;
console.log = Function.prototype;
console.config({maxEntries: Infinity});
console.log = log;

var test = document.createElement('div');
test.className = 'test';
document.body.appendChild(test);
for (var i=0; i<0xffff; ++i) {
  var char = String.fromCharCode(i);
  test.textContent = 'a' + char + 'b';
  if (test.clientHeight > 1) {
    console.log(i.toString(16) + ': ' + JSON.stringify(char));
  }
}
document.body.removeChild(test);
```

```css
.test {
  width: 0;
  line-height: 1px;
}
div.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes I am looking for the soft wrap opportunity rules that are defined by the browsers and/or the systems, that makes the html lines stop at some point and continue next line. I am writting some javascript linecounter that measures words after words if a line fits in a text bloc, so I wonder if someone who knows precisely the source code of browsers or have typographical knowledge, can tell if I forgot rules in my list or not ?

Comment: @RomainGuillaume You can use JS to get the full list

Comment: Very nice demonstration of JS capabillities, very effective. Thank you!