# %s minimum field width in the presence of unicode characters

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, printf

So, here's my problem:

If someone wants to output visually aligned strings using `printf`, they'll obviously use `%<n>s` (where `<n>` is the minimum field width). And this works just fine, unless one of the strings contains unicode (UTF-8) characters.

Take this very basic example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* s1 = "\u03b1\u03b2\u03b3";
    char* s2 = "abc";

    printf("'%6s'\n", s1);
    printf("'%6s'\n", s2);

    return 0;
}
```

which will produce the following output:

```
'αβγ'
'   abc'
```

This isn't all that surprising, because printf of course doesn't know that `\u03b1` (which consists of two characters) only produces a single glyph on the output device (assuming UTF-8 is supported).

Now assume that i generate `s1` and `s2`, but have no control over the format string used to output those variables. My current understanding is that nothing i could possibly do to `s1` would fix this, because i'd have to somehow fool `printf` into thinking that `s1` is shorter than it actually is. However, since i also control `s2`, my current solution is to add a non-printing character to `s2` for each unicode character in `s1`, which would look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* s1 = "\u03b1\u03b2\u03b3";
    char* s2 = "abc\x06\x06\x06";

    printf("'%6s'\n", s1);
    printf("'%6s'\n", s2);

    return 0;
}
```

This will produce the desired output (even though the actual width no longer corresponds to the specified field width, but i'm willing to accept that):

```
'αβγ'
'abc'
```

For context:

The example above is only to illustrate the unicode-problem, my actual code involves printing numbers with SI-prefixes, only one of which (`µ`) is a unicode character. Therefore i would generate strings containing only up to one normal or unicode character (which is why i can accept the resulting offset in the field-width).

So, my questions are:

- Is there a better solution for this?
- Is `\x06` (ACK) a sensible choice (i.e. a character without undesired side-effects)?
- Can you think of any problems with this approach?

Comment: Really doubt there's a better solution to this. The character to choose and whether or not this will cause problems only depends on where the output is supposed to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since the non ascii is restricted to µ, I believe there is a solution. I've taken value of µ to be `\u00b5`. Replace it with the correct value

I've coded a small function `myPrint` which takes input the string and the width n. You should be able to modify the code below to fit to your needs.

The function searches for all occurrences of µ and increments that much of width to the string

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myPrint(char* string, int n)
{
  char* valueOfNu = "\u00b5";
  for(int i=0;string[i]!='\0';i++)
  {
    if(string[i]==valueOfNu[0] && string[i+1]==valueOfNu[1])
      n++;
  }

  printf("%*s",n,string);
}


int main(void)
{
    char* s1 = "ab\u00b5";
    char* s2 = "abc";

    myPrint(s1,6);
    printf("\n");
    myPrint(s2,6);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that violates my constraint of not being able to modify the format string. My actual use case looks something like this: `printf("x=%sm\n", si_print(x))` where `si_print()` is written by me, but the code calling `printf()` isn't.

Comment: @FelixG Sorry. But I still feel it's problematic to use non printable characters. For instance, if the output is being redirected to a file, the file stores the characters and would display those weird looking rectangular symbols where the non printables should be. Another problem I can see is if someone tries to modify the string.  For instance,`printf("a\x06");` prints `a`. But if someone decides to append a character to the string, say 'a', `printf("a\x06a");` prints `aj` instead of `aa`. Since you mentioned SI units being used, I feel this has a probability of occurring.

Comment: The output being redirected to a file is definitely a concern, i haven't tried that yet. As for the other issue, while `printf("a\x06a")` does output `aj`, `printf("a%sa", "\x06")`(which is closer to my use-case) doesn't. I definitely agree though, that the usage of non printable characters feels risky, which is why i posted this question.

Comment: Okay, i've just tested what it would look like after writing to a file, and the results are unfortunately very messy (as you expected).

Comment: @FelixG after taking everything into consideration, I feel the best thing to do is use `\u00a0` which is the non-breaking space. It is non ascii. You can  use it along with the normal space `'  '` to adjust the size. Since its a printable character, it shouldn't be much of an issue even if it prints a space. Only problems are it prevents word wrap and that someone may mistake it to a normal space causing problems. But looking at other options, I feel its the second best thing to do (first being, modifying the printf directly). Does your use case support using nbsp?

Comment: @FelixG I found out about `\u200c`. There's a whole bunch of spaces here at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515365/are-there-other-whitespace-codes-like-nbsp-for-half-spaces-em-spaces-en-space