# Preserve whitespace between <span>s in Vue

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3

In my Vue 3 app, I want to highlight words in a text, such as in the following HTML:

```css
span {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<span>foo</span> 
<span>bar</span> 
baz 
qux
```

However, Vue removes the whitespace between tags, so the gaps between the `<span>`s disappear:

```css
span {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<span>foo</span><span>bar</span> baz qux
```

**How can I preserve the whitespace between the `<span>`s?** I cannot use `&nbsp;` as the spaces should break and none of the [other white space entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515365/are-there-other-whitespace-codes-like-nbsp-for-half-spaces-em-spaces-en-space) has the same size as a usual space.

Comment: how are you adding the spans? the issue is in that code

Comment: You mean linebreaks?

Comment: the OP's concern is 100% valid, I have seen people in other forums say that "we should not rely on a framework to handle our whitespace", but the argument is: if html preserves the whitespace, why should vue remove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so apparently, I'm not the first one to stumble across that behavior, which I would name a bug:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/pull/1600

By default, Vue removes whitespace between elements for compression purposes - other than browsers, which reduce such whitespace to a single space. In Vue 2 it was possible to change the config to preserve whitespace. In Vue 3 this is not possible (yet).

However, there are some workarounds and as mentioned in a comment [1], whitespace is only removed if it contains linebreaks. Therefore, by removing the linebreaks in the above example's source code, the snippet behaves as expected:

```html
<span>foo</span> <span>bar</span> 
baz
qux
```

[1] https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/pull/1600#issuecomment-747162894

Answer (score 13):

IMO this is totally a bug, because:

1. native html behaves in a different way.
2. [the documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/dev/packages/vue-template-compiler#options) the behaviour should default to preserving the whitespace.
3. vue 2 didn't have this problem.

There is a vue `compilerOptions` option called `whitespace` that according to [the documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/dev/packages/vue-template-compiler#options) should default to `'preserve'`, but it does not.

To set it to `'preserve'` in webpack use this config:

```
{
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
        compilerOptions: {
            // preserve is supposed to be the default
            // see: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/dev/packages/vue-template-compiler#options
            // but as of 2022-01-13 (vue 3.2.26)
            whitespace: 'preserve',
        },
    },
},
```

Or if you are rendering your components on the fly (with dom templates) use this:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({...});
app.config.compilerOptions.whitespace = 'preserve';
app.mount('#app');
```

The documentation (at the time of writting):

> `whitespace`
>
> - Type: string
> - Valid values: 'preserve' | 'condense'
> - Default: 'preserve'
>
> The default value `'preserve'` handles whitespaces as follows:
>
> - A whitespace-only text node between element tags is condensed into a
>   single space.
> - All other whitespaces are preserved as-is.
>
> If set to `'condense'`:
>
> - A whitespace-only text node between element tags is removed if it
>   contains new lines. Otherwise, it is condensed into a single space.
> - Consecutive whitespaces inside a non-whitespace-only text node are
>   condensed into a single space.
>
> Using condense mode will result in
> smaller compiled code size and slightly improved performance. However,
> it will produce minor visual layout differences compared to plain HTML
> in certain cases.

Comment: I might have referenced the documentation for vue 2,
I cannot find the compilerOptions document for vue 3, but here in this commit they added the whitespace feature to vue 3 and defaulted to `'condense'` https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/pull/1600/commits/1c42f3a37db3e1da19653d8294c30f251ea16bc8